# Check if item.Name = Name (variable from component) in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2, angular2-routing

How can I check if "item.Name" equals "name" from mypage.ts in *ngIf?

mypage.ts:

```
  ...
    export class myPage {

        public name: any;
        public data: string;

        constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public params: NavParams, public http: Http) {
            this.name = params.get("name");
        }
    ...
```

mypage.html (line 2 not working-> should be something like "if item.Name=name"):

```
 <ion-card *ngFor="let item of data">
    <ion-icon name="trash" *ngIf="item" [name] = "item.Name" ></ion-icon>
    <p>Name: {{item.Name}}</p>
  </ion-card>
```

thanks and best regards

Comment: try *ngIf="item.name === name" instead.

Comment: aaah, forgot that second =, thanks a lot!

Comment: @dzitrus use 3 `=` not 2